# ServiceStack cache - jQuery ajax and JSONP

Tags: web-services, servicestack

**Is there any way to force cache even when using ajax with JSONP?**

Please see below three cases and results:

**#1.** Request **from same host (save as page making the request) and with no JSONP** - cache works corecctly.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "http://samehost.com",
    data: "{ 'format': 'json' }",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }

});
```

**#2.** Request from **different host with no JSONP**, I get `same origin policy` error.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "http://differenthost.com",
    data: "{ 'format': 'json' }",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }

});
```

**#3.** Request from different host and with JSONP the cache does not seems to work - it takes `2-3 sec` to load, where in case `#1 about 70-100ms`

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "http://differenthost.com",
    data: "{ 'format': 'json' }",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }

});
```

Repeating my question, **is there any way to force cache even when using ajax with JSONP?**

---

Below you can see my ServiceStack settings.

Globas.asax.vb

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Public Class HelloAppHost
        Inherits AppHostBase

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("Web Services", GetType(Wrapper).Assembly)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Configure(ByVal container As Container)

            ' Routes
            Routes.Add(Of GetData)("/GetData").Add(Of GetData)("/GetData/{*}")

            ' Cache & Cors 
            container.Register(Of ICacheClient)(New MemoryCacheClient())
            Plugins.Add(New Cors.CorsFeature())


        End Sub

    End Class


    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim apphost = New HelloAppHost()
        apphost.Init()

    End Sub

End Class
```

WS.vb

```
Public Class Wrapper

    <EnableCors()>
    Public Class WrapperGetData
        Inherits Service

        Implements IService(Of GetData)
        Public Function Execute(ByVal request As GetData) As Object Implements ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService(Of GetData).Execute

        Dim cacheKey As String = "GetDataKey"
        Dim expireInTimespan = New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)

        Return Me.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
          MyBase.Cache,
          cacheKey,
          expireInTimespan,
          Function()
            Return request.HandleRequest()
          End Function
        )

        End Function

    End Class
End Class
```